# VSE: Why is the first part of my sound cut off?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

In track 1 of the Video Sequence Editor, I inserted the same piece of audio several times:

[image]

But when I render out the video, the sound byte sounds different on every occurence.
When I extract the audio track from the video and take a look at the waveform in Audacity, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, in most cases the first part of the sound is cut off by Blender, each time at a different location in the waveform.

Could someone explain to me why this is?
Of course I could fix this issue by starting each audio fragment with a short piece of silence, but that would make it harder to position my sounds at the exact right position in my video.

This is the sound file I'm using: http://www.mediafire.com/file/1nonz7niy3502xw/Bounce.wav/file

Comment: Could you provide an example of the audio-file so we can try to replicate your issue?

Comment: You can find the sound file here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/1nonz7niy3502xw/Bounce.wav/file

Comment: Never checked this but you're quite right. The sound profiles look different. According to a little chat on the vse channel (https://blender.chat/channel/vse), @snu pointed me to the existence of a "Render Audio" only possibility (menu Render > Render Audio). There, you can specify the "Accuracy" level of the audio file (lower numbers give better quality). So, when I rendered your sound file with the level set to accuracy=128, the wave profiles in Audacity became virtual identical. I don't know how to set this accuracy level from within the regular rendering (Ctrl+F12). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it.